# Disabling the user interaction of all subviews within a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, user-interaction

I have a tableview and a view beneath it for buttons.
I want to disable the user interaction of all the subviews within the tableview, however scrolling of the tableview should not be disabled.
This is required on clicking of 'Preview' button.
The button view should not be disabled.
Suggestions welcome.
 i tried the following. but this doesn't enable the scrolling nor the button interactions.

```
    - (IBAction)btnPreviewTapped:(id)sender {
for (UIView *eachView in self.view.superview.subviews) {
    if (eachView != formsContentTableView) {
        eachView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
formsContentTableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.buttonView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.btnPreview setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

Comment: isn't it an option to put the view with the buttons on top of the tableView? it would solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found another solution based on what was suggested, whick will not work for disabling user interaction for components within content view, but will disable the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, which was also expected.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if(self.bIsPreview)
      return nil;
 else
return indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a property `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isPreview;`, assign it NO as initial value `self.isPreview = NO;` and then in the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you create your cell subviews, I will check

```
if(self.isPreview) { 
    subview1.userInteractionEnabled = NO; 
    subview2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    // ... etc 
}
```

and then set in your IBAction as follows:

```
-(IBAction)btnPreviewTapped:(id)sender {
    if(self.isPreview) {
        self.isPreview = NO;
    } else {
        self.isPreview = YES;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

`-reloadData` method will redraw the visible cells and their subviews, but depending on `self.isPreview` the subviews will or will not react on user's touch.

Comment: This looks like a reasonable idea, but why not just disable the cells?  `cell.userInteractionEnabled = !self.isPreview;`

Comment: Good point. But OP says that `This is required on clicking of 'Preview' button. The button view should not be disabled`, so I took this approach, as I wasn't sure if this button is one of the cell subviews or not.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this solution. I have not added the button view inside the table view. But still I can't use cell.userInteractionEnabled = !self.isPreview , because I am using different custom cells in the table view.

Comment: Instead of reloading the data in the table view it would be more efficient to just loop over the currently visible cells (`[tableView visibleCells]`), although off the top of my head I'm not sure if this captures all currently loaded cells or just the ones that are actually visible.